# How do I create Upload only permission in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, team-sites

I would like to know how I can create upload only permission level so users are only able to upload documents.

Comment: Are you sure you want that? If you ever give those people access to a list with metadata you will need a curator to finalize the upload

Comment: What if you want them to upload but not be able to see the other files in that folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to create a custom permission level with at least `add and view items` as the following;

[image]

**To create a permission level**

- Open the site collection site (the root site not a subsite)
- Go to site setting.
- below Users and Permission > Click on Site Permission.
- From the above ribbon, > click on permission level to be able to create a new permission level.

[image]

For more details check

- [How to create a new SharePoint permissions level](https://billing.plexhosted.com/knowledgebase/278/How-to-create-a-new-SharePoint-2013-permissions-level-.html)
- [Sharepoint upload permission](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/40b31ca1-1ade-42f0-a984-c16ab266f423/sharepoint-upload-permission?forum=sharepointadmin)
- [Configure custom permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx)
- [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: This doesn't stop anyone with those Upload permissions from seeing anything uploaded into that folder.

Answer (score 6):

Create a new permission level named **Uploaders** and check the permissions *Open*, *Add Items*, *View Items* and *View Pages*. Then grant the permission level to the users and groups who should be able to upload documents but not edit and delete them.

You can manage permission levels from Site Settings > Site Permissions > Permission Levels

Be careful, as this doesnt stop them from being able to click on New/ document, or folder, ss etc, so not quite an "upload only" permissions, sadly.